# Ionic Cannot assign to read only property 'property' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm working on an Ionic app with Angular framework and NGRX  but I have a problem with selected checkbox

The problem is this:

First, I load some vehicle list from DB with a service, next, I set the property selected to false:

```
this.vehicleService.loadVehicles().subscribe(data => {
  this.vehicles = data.map(v => { v.selected = false; return v; });;
});
```

then, I send the `vehicles` variable to another component where I paint the ion-checkboxes

```
<app-devices-menu *ngIf="vehicles !== undefined" [vehicles]="vehicles"
  (selectedDevices)="selectedVehicles($event)" (currentDevice)="currentVehicle($event)">
</app-devices-menu>
```

This is my app-devices-menu component ts

```
@Input() vehicles: VehicleItem[];
@Output() selectedDevices = new EventEmitter<VehicleItem[]>();
@Output() currentDevice = new EventEmitter<VehicleItem>();

constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }

setSelectedDevices(d: VehicleItem) {
  this.currentDevice.emit(d);
  this.selectedDevices.emit(this.vehicles.filter(v => v.selected === true));
}
```

html

```
<ion-menu side="end" class="devices-menu"  menuId="devices" contentId="main">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let v of vehicles">
      <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="setSelectedDevices(v)" [(ngModel)]="v.selected" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>{{ v.description }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-menu>
```

Everything is working correctly at this point. I want to set in the ngrx store the current vehicle (Which is the last device I clicked) and the list of selected devices. But the problem is when I dispach the selectedVehicles action by changing the selected prperty from true to false, i get this error
[image]

This is my function where I get the event from the other component and then I dispach the action:

```
selectedVehicles(ev: VehicleItem[]) {
  const selectedDevices: VehicleItem[] = [...ev];
  this.store.dispatch(actions.setSelectedVehicles({ vehicles: selectedDevices }));
}
```

and this is my reducer where I set the new array in the store

```
const reducerMap = createReducer(initialMapState,    
    /* VEHICLE LIST ---------------------------- */
    on(actions.setSelectedVehicles, (state, { vehicles }) => ({ ...state, selectedVehicles: [...vehicles] })),    
);

export function mapReducer(state, action) {
    return reducerMap(state, action);
}
```

I think that js works by reference and I can't modify the store could be a problem there 'couse I can't set the propery selected false if the item is already in the store. That's why I need to generate a new array, but It seems not to work whit the spread operator in any point [...]

How can I fix this issue and change the store with the selected vehicles and current vehicle?

Comment: what does the `VehicleItem` interface/class looks like?

Comment: What happens if you switch from [(ngModel)]="v.selected" to [ngModel]="v.selected"

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

For solution:

```
 this.vehicules_copy = this.vehicules.map((item: any) => ({ ...item }));
```

and use this variable in html and ts to get the values

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let v of vehicles_copy; let i = index">
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="vehicules_copy[i].selected" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>{{ v.description }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```